# Why am I getting "SytaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have just download and install Python 3.5.2 , I have two python files that I want to run from CMD but I got the problem

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

The problem code reads:

```
print '####### ' + modulename
###########################################################
def sqlihunt(dork , filename ):
```

Comment: Please post the code where the print statement is executed

Comment: print  '#######    ' + modulename

###########################################################
def sqlihunt(dork , filename ):

Comment: Please edit you question to include the (well formatted) code you are trying to execute.

Comment: Edited offending code into the question.  Improved wording.

Comment: I know this sounds crazy, but this is because you are missing parentheses. Where, you ask? When you call `print`.

Answer (score 1):

print statement in python 3 requires parentheses.

e.g.: `print(whatever you want to print goes here)`